# Windows, WinSCP, through one Redhat Proxy server to the real server behind it

Tags: windows-7, networking, ssh, backup, redhat-enterprise-linux

Here is what I need to accomplish. I have a Windows 7 Desktop computer. I also have a cluster of RedHat servers that provide services to my users. All of the RedHat servers back up to one of the servers in the cluster and I need to get the backups off of that server and onto my Windows system using WinSCP.

Here is where the problem comes in. All of the traffic to my cluster is proxied through a single IP address/hostname/device. The Unix system that is porxying all the traffic has a routable IP and I'm currently hopping from/through that server to the backup server, coping the backups to it via scp (the routable server) and then using WinSCP to move it to my Windows box and onto an external hard-drive. The problem is that the server that I'm using as a go-between to move this data no longer has the drive capacity needed.

So to sum this all up, I need a way to copy files from a redhat server while bouncing through another redhat server onto a windows computer. To just a little insult to injury here, I cannot create a share on the Windows device and go the other way coping the files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that your proxied servers only have one interface and you are unable to get a remote shell on them specifically ? Usually, in production environnements, this kind of setup includes another network interface on the servers connected to an administration network which isn't routed to the outside, used for this kind of purposes.

Comment: How are you connecting to the "proxy" computer? Telnet? SSH?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SSH tunnel. You can find lots of guides to this, for ex:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel